# Get the value of Checkbox and hidden input element

Tags: jquery

Htlm as follows :

```
<table class="tablesorter">
 <g:each in="${vehicleInstanceList}" status="i" var="vehicleInstance">
 <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}" id ="rows">
    <td >
      <g:checkBox id = "isActive_${i}" class="isActive" name="isActive"  value="${vehicleInstance?.isActive}" />
      <input type="hidden" value="${vehicleInstance?.id}" name="vehicleId" id="isActive_${i}_" />
     </td>
</tr>
```

and Jquery :

```
  $(".isActive").click(function() {
     var checkBox_id = $(this).attr("id");            // getting the id of checkbox
     var isActive =          // get the value of checkbox
     var  vehicleId  =      // get the value of hidden input element

  });
```

i have to get the value of checkbox and hidden input element how can i do it?
isActive is a boolean type and i want answer in terms of true/false , if checked true else false

```
  var isActive = $('#'+checkBox).is(':checked');  i have tried to get value of checkbox but it always gives output as false
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#elementID").val();` will get the value of the selected element. For the checkbox, you can use `$(this)` as your selector, as you did for getting the `id`.

Comment: $(this).val(); gives output as on i have tried something like this    var isActive = $('#'+checkBox).is(':checked');  // always false                      var  vehicleId  =  $('#'+checkBox+'_').val();// gives correct output

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var isActive =          $(this).is(":checked");
var  vehicleId  =      $(this).closest("td").find(":hidden").val();
```

Comment: isActive is a boolean i want output in terms of true/false if checked true else false

Comment: vehicleId is not in next td its within that td , so closest wont work

Comment: Closest will find the containing td and not the next td.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1. Get the parent of the check box who is actually the parent for that hidden also.
2. Find the hidden field in the parent.

Simple... !

sample snippet

```
 $('.isActive').click(function(){

        var isActive = $(this).is(':checked');

        console.log(isActive);

        var _vehicle = $(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val();

        console.log(_vehicle);


    });
```

Fiddle link for Assistance : http://jsfiddle.net/baELR/2/